# Method call from a different assembly

Tags: c#, .net

Let's suppose that program A loads assembly A and assembly B. These 3 entities live under the same app domain. Program A can access public methods and properties of assembly A and B.

Is it possible that Assembly A can access somehow public methods and properties of Assembly B without reloading the assembly? If not, and assembly B needs to call `Assembly.Load`, will the runtime understand that is already loaded and return a reference, or the assembly will be loaded from scratch in a separate memory space and be assigned a different reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AppDomain.GetAssemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) to see if an assembly is loaded already, but it is also handled internally and Assembly.Load won't load the same assembly into the same domain twice.